# If characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)^n$, then show $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

I have a problem about matrix similarity:

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^n$. I want to show that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are similar matrices.

I know that both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have $1$ as their only eigenvalue, with algebraic multiplicity $n$. But I don't know how to use this fact to prove their similarity. Can anyone give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: Seems oddly similar to this deleted post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846216/s-and-s-1-are-similar

Comment: @pancini But how can I find a solution? I can't see that page.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Can I ask you to provide a complete proof, please?

Answer (score 1):

Let $J$ be the Jordan Canonical form of $A$. Then $J=P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible matrix. So $J^{-1}=P^{-1}A^{-1}P$. Now observe that $J$ and $J^{-1}$ are similar. So $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are similar.

Comment: This is a valid proof but worth mentioning that showing $J$ and $J^{-1}$ are similar is a tricky if the the field is not algebraically closed. Alternatively you can use the fact that "similar over a field extension $L/k$ implies similar over $k$" and just assume $k$ is algebraically closed.